How to get ditto result in real owner instead of _unknown:_unknown on a mounted (target disk mode) other Mac?
I have mounted (target disk mode) an x86 Mac on another x86 Mac. Both are running macOS Sonoma (latest).
But when I use sudo ditto to copy a directory over, or use sudo touch to create a file, the resulting file seems to get owner:user as 99:99 (unknown:_unknown). In the Finder this is displayed as owner myself.
What is happening? And how do I get around it?

The target "disk" is mounted with the nowners flag. In finder terminology, "set to ignore permissions".

It is more that anything that is mounted as a 'removable device' is mounted with no-owners. Changing that flag in Finder did not work but using diskutil did (see answer).

Have a look at vsdbutil.

Interesting, thank you. I did not know vsdbutil (deprecated). But (see below) diskutil did the trick too.

'Ownership' is turned off on the mounted drive. It was not possible to fix this with Finder (enable ownership in the Info panel, not even with admin authentication), but
sudo diskutil enableOwnership <device> (where device is something like /dev/disk5s1) worked.
